# Sorting Report data in a ReportViewer using a BindingSource

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, reportviewer, bindingsource

I'm trying to get ReportViewer to display data from a BindingSource  (VB.Net Winforms).

I built the report on the underlying dataset.  Then I configured the Data Source Instance to the BindingSource.  I thought that would apply the sorting, filtering, etc.  But it just looks like the data is coming from the dataset instead of the BindingSource.

I suspect I'm missing something simple.

Update: Or maybe it isn't so simple - I posted this a few days ago and still nobody knows the answer!  Maybe I'm trying to do something that can't be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution I used.  You put the data from the BindingSource into a DataTable and then have the Report use the DataTable.

```
    ReportViewer1.Reset()
    Dim dt As DataTable
    dt = DirectCast(Form1.ProgActnBindingSource.Current, DataRowView).DataView.ToTable

    Dim rs = New ReportDataSource
    rs.Name = "name"
    rs.Value = dt

    ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rs)
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "projectname.Report1.rdlc"

    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to specify the sorting in the report (in the RDL), since it applies its own sorting logic.